Is it possible in FullCalendar to set the size in which a MaxEvents popover starts
Is it possible to set a max content height for all events within a cell so that if a specified height is exceeded then any further overflowing events will fall into the max event popover.
I know it is possible to set a number of events but I want this to be dynamic and based on a size breakpoint (dayMaxEvents=true). I don't want the events to all try to take up the full space of the view
this diagram shows the type of behaviour I want to achieve

I've tried overriding the CSS class .fc-daygrid-day-events height however this does not effect the point at which the popover triggers
